# Make iPhone Simulator case sensitive on file access

Tags: file, ios-simulator, case-sensitive

It's known that when accessing files in iPhone simulator the case of chars doesn't matter. Is it possible to setup iPhone Simulator to not ignore cases?

Otherwise I can compare file path from my code with file path from disk. Then what method to use to get real file path with right cases corresponding to file path from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with script on build phase:

```
echo "list all files in [$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME]"
cd "$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH"
find . -type f > "$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH"/filelist.txt
```

And added some code to find file path in filelist.txt:

```
BOOL file_found = NO;
for (NSString* file_path in AllFilesList) // AllFilesList keeps list from allfiles.txt
{
    if ([file_path rangeOfString: relPath].location == 2) // 2 because all paths start with './'
    {
        file_found = YES;
        break;
    }
}
if (!file_found)
{
    NSLog (@"!!! ERROR !!! file not found: [%@]", relPath);
    for (NSString* file_path in AllFilesList)
    {
        if ([file_path rangeOfString: relPath options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == 2)
        {
            NSLog (@"   corresponding file may be: [%@]", relPath);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you report the bug to Apple? iPhone simulator should be case sensitive the same way the devices are.

Comment: Apple says in documentation that it is filesystem-depended. If we format HDD volume as case sensitive system, Simulator and all other apps will be case sensitive.